# Is it possible to create a native library in Xamarin?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I want to create a library in Xamarin and export that library so i can use it in Android Studio and xCode to develop native UI/UX. I would also like to distribute this library so other developers can create their own interfaces. Is this possible?

Is is posible to export a .jar of .aar and the respective iOS library for use on native code?

Comment: You can share an CIL assembly to other Xamarin users but you can not create a `native` library for use in Xcode/AS/... as it would require the other developers to embed Mono into their apps. This is not currently supported via Xamarin

Comment: And what about "Embedded Assemblies" in the Xamarin Enterprise version?

Comment: `Embedded Assemblies` are just that, the compiled Assemblies (AOT'd or not) are linked into the Mono runtime, *kind-of* like `mkbundle` does. This feature is really helpful in the Android environment as it creates an additional headache to those trying to reverse engineer your CIL assemblies. Not to say that iOS does not have that problem, but since those assemblies are required to be AOT'd it is much tougher to R.E. them (not impossible, but harder)