# Is it possible to create native Android and iOS library with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Is it possible to create a native Android and iOS library with Xamarin?
For example, create an .AAR library

Comment: Check the comments :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656057/is-it-posible-to-create-a-native-library-in-xamarin

Comment: @G.hakim thanks. Does this mean No? Kind of missed opportunity for Xamarin

Comment: yeah it means no and yes a missed opportunity but it is not needed anyway so nothing to worry

Comment: @SushiHangover and EvZ: The question you put as being the duplicate of this doesn't say anything aboiut iOS

Comment: There is a preview tool now available that allows turning C# libraries into native libraries for use in other programming languages: https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/index

Comment: @BrendanZagaeski Oh thanks!

Comment: @BrendanZagaeski how far is that from Release? this year?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not in the loop on any info about timelines. I just noticed this question while skimming Stack Overflow, remembered the preview tool, and thought it might be of interest.